# How does $\log_2(A)-\log_2(B)+\log_2(c)$ not equal $\log_2(\frac{Bc}{A})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_2(A)-\log_2(B)+\log_2(c)$

How does this equal $\log_2(\frac{Ac}{B})$? Does it not follow from the order of operations that it would be addition first then subtraction?

I'm having  hard time understanding why it isn't $\log_2(\frac{Bc}{A})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of operations says that addition and subtraction are performed left-to-right, so this is
\begin{equation*}
  (\log_2(A)-\log_2(B)) + \log_2(C)
    = \log_2\left(\frac{A}{B}\right) + \log_2(C)
    = \log_2\left(\frac{A*C}{B}\right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: The result doesn't depend on order of operations, and you don't need to perform l-r (your result is correct of course).

Comment: @gnometorule From the OP's point of view, it *does* depend on order of operations --- if the addition is performed first, you get the wrong answer (regarding $-$ as a binary operation rather than a unary minus).

Comment: @rogerl No, if the addition is done first AND the subtraction done backwards only then does OP get his result

Comment: @Soke ? $\log_2(A) - (\log_2(B) + \log_2(C)) = \log_2(A) - \log_2(B*C) = \log_2\left(\frac{A}{B*C}\right)$.

Comment: I totally forgot about the fact that C is also C/1 when multiplying. Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: @rogerl Exactly. You only get OP's result if you do that backwards. I don't see your point.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the two fundamental properties of the logarithms:
$$\log_xy + \log_xz = \log_xyz$$
and
$$
\log_xy^z= z\log_xy.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Addition and subtraction have the same precedence and you evaluate them from left to right. Therefore $x-y+z=(x-y)+z$ rather than $x-(y+z)$ since you start on the left and then move right.

This is because subtraction is actually secretly addition, you're just adding the opposite of the second number so $x-y$ is actually $x+(-y)$. So $x-y+z=x+(-y)+z$ and then you do the first addition first. Although actually addition is nice since if you make everything into addition, it doesn't matter what order you do it since addition is associative which means $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$ so order doesn't matter.

Since you asked about order of operations I won't mention log rules, but if you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask.